# except the @everyone role in log messages (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to log changes to the roles of a User with a bot[[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwWu8.png), but I want to exclude the @@everyone role from the changed roles.

Do you know how I can do that?

Here's the code I am currently using:

```
    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        if before.roles != after.roles:

            embed = Embed(
                colour = discord.Colour.blue(),
                description=f"{after.mention}'s Rollen haben sich aktualisiert:",
                timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
            )
            embed.set_author(name=after.name,
            icon_url=after.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {after.id}")

            fields = [("Before:", ", ".join([r.mention for r in before.roles]), False),
                      ("After:", ", ".join([r.mention for r in after.roles]), False)]

            for name, value, inline in fields:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

            await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Your `@Cog.listener()` needs to be `@commands.Cog.listener()`

Comment: I don't think so, because I imported this [`from discord.ext.commands import Cog`]
 and the code itself is working

Comment: I've post and edit my answer below, now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in different server and find that `@everyone` has unique `@id` by server.

so maybe you should use `Member.Roles.Role.name` instead. (or you should store the @everyone id) I mean, no one will name the role exactly "@everyone" right? (unexpectedly it's a legit naming)

here's the test. The first print is your code, the second is @everyone excluded.

```
@commands.command()
    async def test(self, context):
        roles = context.author.roles
        roles2 = []
        for r in roles:
            if r.name != '@everyone':
                roles2.append(r.mention)
        print("Before:", ", ".join([r.mention for r in roles]))
        print(f"@everyone exclude: {roles2}")
```